# using variable in dynamic query

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  statement VARCHAR2(4000);
  BALANCING_ID INTEGER;
  VAULT_TILL_ID INTEGER;
  balancingid INTEGER := 16437;
BEGIN
  statement := 'SELECT EOD_BALANCING_ID, VAULT_TILL_ID
  FROM MBCUSR2UT2.CASH_BALANCING
  WHERE eod_balancing_id = :balancingid';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement
  INTO BALANCING_ID, VAULT_TILL_ID;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: ' || BALANCING_ID || ', Vault: ' || VAULT_TILL_ID);
END;
```

I have this query and it is not working due to error in line

> WHERE eod_balancing_id = :balancingid

saying

```
Error report -
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-06512: at line 10
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

but when I use directly like

> WHERE eod_balancing_id = 16437';

it is working fine why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use dynamic SQL? IN your case it does not seem to be needed.

Anyway, would be this one:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement INTO BALANCING_ID, VAULT_TILL_ID USING balancingid;
```

Comment: I am just exploring oracle if there is a way to use variable so that it is easy for me to rerun the query just by changing variable value.